# Unable to set width to <a> tags

Tags: css

I am trying to give the  tags a width of 20% inside this ul, but I am unable. Any help would be grateful. I am able to set the width of the li items, but I am looking to set the width to the `<a>`.

```
<nav>
<ul class="navigation">
<li class="main_nav_li"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="main_nav_li"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="main_nav_li"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li class="main_nav_li"><a href="#">Stylist</a></li>
<li class="main_nav_li"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>


<style>
nav{
    width:98%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:3em;

}

.nav{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

a{ 
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10%;
    font-size: 1em ;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
        font-family: 'Happy Monkey', cursive;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't set a width to an inline element.

Add `display: inline-block;` and it will work

```
a{ 
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10%;
    font-size: 1em ;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    font-family: 'Happy Monkey', cursive;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This does not work with the code as given: http://jsfiddle.net/KzMxK/1/.  I got is working by applying the width and inline-block to the li in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are inline elements by default. You must use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Block-level elements allow you to set width, inline ones do not.

Comment: Note that elements that have `display:inline-block` are inline-level, not block-level. Also, *replaced* inline elements can have a width set on them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rKwkH/1/

I had to apply the `width` and `display:inline-block` to the `li`:

```
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```